# has_perm method gives False even if user has pemission

Tags: django, permissions

I added permission <Permission: blog | post | Can add post> to a user using shell. It worked because in admin site it is added.

Nevertheless when I run below methods in a shell it shows no permission was added.

```
user2.get_user_permissions()         -> set()
user2.has_perm('blog.add_post')      -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Django's permissions do not take
effect until you allocate a new instance of the user.

```
user2 = get_user_model().objects.get(email="test@user.com")
print(user2.has_perm("blog.add_post")) # => True
```